# How to call javascript function from php echo?

Tags: javascript, php

Hi all i am trying to call javascript function called loadvideo from php echo and i keep getting errors. I tried two methods

1)first Method i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in

echo ("<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$URL\','image1.jpg')">$item['name']</a> <br/></td>\n");
```

2)second method i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

echo ("<td><a onClick='loadVideo(" . $URL . ");'>$item['name']</a><br/></td>\n");
```

could any one show me how to fix this ?Thanks in advance.

javascript function to call:

```
<script>
  function loadVideo(myFile,myImage) { 
    jwplayer().load([{
      file: myFile,
      image: myImage
    }]);
    jwplayer().play();
  };
</script>
```

Comment: What is it displaying in the HTML? See view source and tell how it is generating.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I get those errors i can't click nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
echo ("<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$URL\','image1.jpg')\">".$item['name']."</a> <br/></td>\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second one to:

```
echo ("<td><a onClick='loadVideo(\"" . $URL . "\");'>$item['name']</a><br/></td>\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have check second method. There you missing quote of php variable.

Here is updated method

First method updated::

```
echo ("<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$URL','image1.jpg')\">$item['name']</a> <br/></td>\n");
```

Second method :

```
    echo ("<td><a onClick='loadVideo(" . $URL . ");'>".$item['name']."</a><br/></td>\n");
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

change First one with

```
echo ("<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo(".$URL.",'image1.jpg')\">".$item['name']."</a> <br/></td>\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are small bugs in your code.

Change the first one like this:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$URL\','image1.jpg')\">{$item['name']}</a> <br/></td>\n";
```

And the second one like this:

```
echo "<td><a onClick='loadVideo(" . $URL . ");'>{$item['name']}</a><br/></td>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

**First approach:**

```
echo ("<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('".$URL."','image1.jpg');\">".$item['name']."</a> <br/></td>\n");
```

**Second approach:**

```
echo ("<td><a onclick=\"loadVideo('".$URL."','image1.jpg');\">".$item['name']."</a> <br/></td>\n");
```